# Pythonic way to use the second condition in list comprehensions

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

Let's assume the following function:

```
def myfun(my_list, n, par1=''):
    if par1 == '':
        new_list = [[my_fun2(i,j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
    else:
        new_list = [[my_fun2(i,j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n) if my_fun2(i,n) == par1]
    return new_list
```

As you can see, there are two different scenarios depending on `par1`. I do not like that line 3 and line 5 are almost identical and do not follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. How can this code be improved?

Comment: Check my answer, I don't have your exact functions so it's hard to test it in the same environment, but I reckon it should do the trick

Comment: It would be nice to understand what you actually try to solve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work:

```
new_list = [[my_fun2(i,j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n) if par1 == '' or my_fun2(i,n) == par1]
```

So used like this:

```
def myfun(my_list, n, par1=''):
    return [
               [my_fun2(i,j) for j in range(n)]
               for i in range(n) if par1 == '' or my_fun2(i,n) == par1
           ]
```

Comment: You could also merge the return into line 2, but thats up to you really

Comment: Despite this is a possible solution, I think that the readability is not quite good, so it's missing the "readability counts" rule of the zen of python. IMHO the cascaded list comprehension should be split up.

Comment: Minor note: You don't need the backslashes inside comprehensions (or within parenthesis) :)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need. It turns out that it is more a logical operator problem than list comprehensions :)
Just a little note, I see that if n is pretty big then the solution is not so great since we check par1 == '' at every step.

Answer (score 8):

You could choose the condition function dynamically by using a function that just returns `True` in the first case and one that actually compares the `my_fun2` result with `par1` in the second case:

```
def myfun(my_list, n, par1=''):
    if par1 == '':
        cond = lambda x, y: True
    else:
        cond = lambda i, n: my_fun2(i, n) == par1
    return [[my_fun2(i,j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n) if cond(i,n)]
```

Or by replacing the outer loop with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) in case `par1` isn't an empty string:

```
def myfun(my_list, n, par1=''):
    if par1 == '':
        outer = range(n)
    else:
        # a conditional generator expression
        outer = (i for i in range(n) if my_fun2(i,n) == par1)
    return [[my_fun2(i,j) for j in range(n)] for i in outer]
```

However don't let DRY make the function harder to read, maintain or debug. I, personally, think that your approach is fine (and probably faster) and you probably shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I agree. There is a fine line between DRY and readability.

Comment: @Trarbish well, it's also a question about performance (not only about readability). Your approach will be faster than my generator expression approach (which is probably the fastest not DRY approach mentioned here).

Answer (score 1):

why not use a filter ?

```
from operator import eq
def myfun(my_list, n, par1=''):
    new_list = ([my_fun2(i,j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n))
    if par1 != '':
        new_list = filter(eq(par1),new_list)
    return list(new_list)
```

Comment: I understand that for the future and Python3, list comprehensions are a better way to go over the alternative of using map, filter and reduce.

Comment: Filter in python 3 creates a generator, that is why the return value is surrounded with a list()